# Are there non-trivial two-party stabilizers in bipartite entanglement for product states?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, group-theory, quantum-entanglement, research-level

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.06437) recent paper where the authors discuss finite classification of entanglement types, on pg. 29 in appendix A, it is claimed that in bipartite entanglement for product state $|00\rangle$ there are no non-trivial two-party [stabilizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Fixed_points_and_stabilizer_subgroups). Here, stabilizer is defined as the group of local unitary actions which keep the pure state invariant up to a global phase. However for a generic state $\psi=a|00\rangle+b|11\rangle$ with $a>0,b>0$ it is claimed that there exists such a non-trivial two-party stabilizer given by $$u_A \otimes u_B=e^{i \theta}\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i \alpha_1} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i \alpha_2}\end{array}\right) \otimes\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{-i \alpha_1} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i \alpha_2}\end{array}\right).$$

I don't understand why this is not a valid two-party stabilizer for $|00\rangle$ i.e. why is the condition $a>0,b>0$ necessary for writing the above equation? Maybe a proper derivation of the above equation will provide the answer which the paper does not provide (A similar derivation can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001091), but that doesn't exactly answer my question). However, the above is intuitively obvious because the authors are *defining* entanglement to be local unitary actions on the subsystems such that one such action cancels off the other, quantifying the "spooky action at a distance". So basically we operate two phase shift gates along with a global $U(1)$ phase  $e^{i\theta}$ infront.

To inspect my doubt, I also tried acting on $|00\rangle=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ with $$u_A\otimes u_B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 e^{i \theta } & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & e^{i \text{$\alpha $1}-i \text{$\alpha $2}+i \theta } & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & e^{-i \text{$\alpha $1}+i \text{$\alpha $2}+i \theta } & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i \theta } \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which clearly stabilizes $|00\rangle$ apart from the phase $e^{i\theta}$.

Alternatively, following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1434875/) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001091) I also tried writing the state $|00\rangle$ in Schmidt-form as
$$|00\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=T~~(\text{let})$$ and doing $u_A T u_B^T$ which yielded the same result i.e. $e^{i\theta}T$. (Although I don't understand exactly why there should we act by *transpose* of $u_B$ from the right and not $u_B^{-1}=u_B^{\dagger}$)

I have been doing something terribly wrong in both of these calculations because if truly there was a non-trivial two-party stabilizer for a product state then it would mean (falsely) that a product state is entangled(because then it's entanglement group would be non-trivial(=$U(1)$) as shown in the paper's calculation for the generic state). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stabilizer you have can be factored as $s_A \times s_B$ such that both $s_A \times 1_B$ and $1_A \times s_B$ also stabilize the state $|00⟩$. To be precise, look at eq. 115 from the paper to work out the specific product that would give the stabilizer you have chosen. These stabilizers are what the paper defines as one party stabilizers, namely those that belong to the groups $S_A$ and $S_B$ respectively. Such stabilizers are precisely the ones being modded out in the definition of the entanglement group $$E_{AB} = S_{AB}/({S_A \times S_B}).$$ Note that all of these groups are state-dependent and don't vary smoothly as you vary the states. It's the group $E_{AB}$ that's trivial for the tensor product state, hence characterizing no entanglement. I hope this helps.